# Add method in class

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

````
      class Clock:


       def __init__(self,hours,minutes):```

         self.hours=hours 
         self.minutes=minutes



     def Clock(hours,minutes):
      if hours>9 and minutes>9:
         return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)
      elif hours>9 and minutes<10:
        return str(hours)+":0"+str(minutes)
      elif hours<10 and minutes>9:
        return "0"+str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)
      else:
        return "0"+str(hours)+":"+"0"+str(minutes)
````

And now i want to add an **add** method that when im doing

In: Clock.Clock(5,6)+Clock.Clock(5,6)

Out: 05:0605:06

and i want---

Out: 10:12

How do I do that? I'm lost I've tried everything

Comment: Which language you are talking about?

Comment: I think it's Python.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: its phyton, and i need help with how to approach the _add__ method at this point, because i cant quite figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Without reinventing the wheel, this should point you in the right direction:

```
from datetime import timedelta

timeOne = timedelta(hours=5, minutes=6)
timeTwo = timedelta(hours=5, minutes=6)

print(timeOne + timeTwo)
```

#### Output

```
10:12:00
```